OAuth 2.0 Spotify InternalOAuthError
InternalOAuthError: failed to fetch user profile
    at C:\Users\PAKSHAL\Documents\Pakshal\Projects\Saarang\backend\node_modules\passport-spotify\lib\passport-spotify\strategy.js:151:19
    at passBackControl (C:\Users\PAKSHAL\Documents\Pakshal\Projects\Saarang\backend\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PAKSHAL\Documents\Pakshal\Projects\Saarang\backend\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:157:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:531:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

after refreshing page message gets changed:
TokenError: Invalid authorization code
    at OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (C:\Users\PAKSHAL\Documents\Pakshal\Projects\Saarang\backend\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:373:12)
    at OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (C:\Users\PAKSHAL\Documents\Pakshal\Projects\Saarang\backend\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:420:16)
    at C:\Users\PAKSHAL\Documents\Pakshal\Projects\Saarang\backend\node_modules\passport-oauth2\lib\strategy.js:177:45
    at C:\Users\PAKSHAL\Documents\Pakshal\Projects\Saarang\backend\node_modules\passport-spotify\lib\passport-spotify\strategy.js:81:20
    at passBackControl (C:\Users\PAKSHAL\Documents\Pakshal\Projects\Saarang\backend\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PAKSHAL\Documents\Pakshal\Projects\Saarang\backend\node_modules\passport-oauth2\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:157:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:531:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1696:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)


This happens for different user's ,I tried with three users , two of the users get this problem, one user doesnt get this problem.

'/' -> Hello World

'/auth/spotify' -> 'auth/spotify/callback' -> enter credentials

'/dashboard' -> Welcome, username!
instead of above output of recieving username upon logging in with correct credentials i get those two errors listed.
I am using Oauth 2.0 spotify for logging in my app , i created app in spotify dashboard , took client credentials , secret key and entered correct callback uri, used passport-spotify .
This is what im doing :

Index.js
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/auth');
const groupRoutes = require('./routes/grouproutes');
require('dotenv').config();
require('./config/passport');  // Initialize passport strategy
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
// Middleware for session management
app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// MongoDB connection
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
  .then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected'))
  .catch(err => console.error('MongoDB connection error:', err));

// Auth routes
app.use('/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/group',groupRoutes);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${process.env.PORT || 3000}`);
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello, world!');
  });
});


app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return res.redirect('/auth/spotify');
  }
  res.send(`Welcome, ${req.user.displayName}!`);  // Access user info from Spotify profile
});



Passport.js
const passport = require('passport');
const SpotifyStrategy = require('passport-spotify').Strategy;
const User = require('../models/User');  // Your User model

passport.use(new SpotifyStrategy({
  clientID: process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/spotify/callback",
},
  async function(accessToken, refreshToken, expires_in, profile, done) {
    try {
      // Check if the user already exists
      let user = await User.findOne({ spotifyId: profile.id });

      if (!user) {
        // If user doesn't exist, create a new one
        user = new User({
          spotifyId: profile.id,
          displayName: profile.displayName,
          email: profile.emails[0].value,
          profileImage: profile.photos[0]?.value,
          accessToken,
          refreshToken
        });
        await user.save();
      } else {
        // If user exists, update tokens
        user.accessToken = accessToken;
        user.refreshToken = refreshToken;
        await user.save();
      }

      return done(null, user);
    } catch (err) {
      return done(err, null);
    }
  }
));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(id);
    done(null, user);
  } catch (err) {
    done(err, null);
  }
});



authmiddleware.js
const axios = require('axios');
const User = require('../models/User');

const ensureAuthenticated = async (req, res, next) => {
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;

  if (!authHeader || !authHeader.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'User not authenticated' });
  }

  const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];

  try {
    // Validate the token by making a request to Spotify API
    const response = await axios.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    });

    const spotifyUserData = response.data;

    // Find the user in your MongoDB by spotifyId
    const user = await User.findOne({ spotifyId: spotifyUserData.id });

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: 'User not found in the system' });
    }

    // Attach MongoDB user object to req.user
    req.user = user;

    next(); // Continue to the next middleware or route handler
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Invalid token or session expired' });
  }
};

module.exports = ensureAuthenticated;



User.js (model)
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  spotifyId: { type: String, required: true, unique: true }, // Spotify ID
  displayName: { type: String },  // Spotify username
  email: { type: String },        // Spotify email
  profileImage: { type: String }, // Spotify profile picture
  accessToken: { type: String },  // Spotify OAuth access token
  refreshToken: { type: String }, // Spotify OAuth refresh token
  friends: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }], // Friends in your app
  friendRequests: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }], // Pending friend requests
  activeGroup: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Group', default: null },  // Active group, null if not in any
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);





Turns out it was a silly error for which i wasted half of a day,
Reason:
my spotify app was in developer-mode , so for any user i try to register , i should first go to
spotify dashboard -> click on the app -> settings -> user management -> manually add user to access your app for testing.
When you are ready to deploy go in settings -> extension request -> submit an extension request !
cheers ! thats why always read the docs !!
